# syntax error, unexpected '$_SERVER' (T_VARIABLE)

Tags: php, yii2

I have class with constant variable but I get this error

```
syntax error, unexpected '$_SERVER' (T_VARIABLE)
```

**Here is my code**

```
<?php

namespace common\models;

class EConstant
{

    ....
    const HomeUrl = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/someweb/';
    ....

}
```

What wrong with my code?

Comment: You can't assign $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] as constant. The value must be a constant expression, not (for example) a variable, a property, or a function call.  Refer :  http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php

Comment: When i try to private $querystring = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; i get the same error

Answer (score 2):

You can not do that, instead try this,

```
<?php

class EConstant
{

    protected $homeURL;

    public function __construct() {
         $this->homeURL = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/someweb/';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Saravanan Sampathkumar's answer is proper but not complete.

As Guide states:

> When extending your class from `yii\base\Component` or `yii\base\Object`, it is recommended that you follow these conventions:
>   - If you override the constructor, specify a `$config` parameter as the constructor's last parameter, and then pass this parameter to the parent constructor.
>   - Always call the parent constructor at the end of your overriding constructor.
>   - If you override the `yii\base\Object::init()` method, make sure you call the parent implementation of `init()` at the beginning of your `init()` method.

So it should be:

```
public function __construct($config)
{
    $this->homeURL = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/someweb/';
    parent::__construct($config);
}
```

or `init()` should be used instead like:

```
public function init()
{
    parent::init();
    $this->homeURL = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/someweb/';
}
```

It might be worth to mention that you should not fully trust this `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` variable as it can be tampered. At least check if the incoming value is on the expected values list if possible.